# How does Gmail handle attachments in Android

Tags: java, android, gmail

I want to send an attachment from my app. 
I start an ACTION_SEND intent with the file URI that I want to attach.

I can get a callback to my app when the user clicks SEND, but since uploading the attachment can take a while how do I know if the email is actually sent?

I need to know this since I want to delete the file after. What happens if the file is deleted in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Use thread with handler
and delete the file in handler .post
this might work although u have to test it yourself...